# how can I make a welcome popup window upon visiting the website

Tags: 7

Some clients I have may want a popup when a user visits the site if they have special events going on, and display maybe a flyer in a popup.

How can I force a popup upon a user visiting the site? Is there a module that can accomplish this? If not, what kind of edits am I looking at doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Splashify](https://drupal.org/project/splashify) module, it also have the option to popup on any page.

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user,
>   showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to
>   be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple
>   configuration options.

**or**

You can try [TinyBox (Simple Splash)](https://drupal.org/project/tinybox). see the [demo](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/)

> The main purpose of this module is to provide Splash Screen/Window as
>   simple as possible.

**or**

take a look at [Splash Offer](https://drupal.org/project/splash_offer) module

> Allows the management of one or more "splash offers", which are modal
>   popups with an accept or reject form. If a user accepts the offer then
>   a new page will open with a provided accept url. If they reject the
>   offer, the modal will close.

Answer (score 1):

To make this more maintainable I would load some jquery that just targets a particular piece of content via selector and uses ui.dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it in the template files with a cookie; it is not pretty, but it gets it done.

For example, in every page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom action/trigger. On front page content view, load the flyer/event page in a lightbox (or shadowbox) popup, and redirect them to an alternate front page that doesn't set off that trigger.