# Registration pop up for new guest users

Tags: users

I have a drupal 7 site.

I have users that are coming to many pages of my site (not only home page) from different sources on the internet.

My goal is that when a guest user is entering the site, no matter which page, he will get nice popup that will offer him to register to the site. On the popup, I will write short text explaining the benefits of the site, even put a video (if possible).

I saw that in many sites, I get a popup message on top on the site (the rest of the site becomes dark) that offer me to register. I want to do something similar.

Can someone help me achieve this goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I make a welcome popup window upon visiting the website](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/how-can-i-make-a-welcome-popup-window-upon-visiting-the-website)

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to [splashify](https://drupal.org/project/splashify):

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user,
>   showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to
>   be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple
>   configuration options.